# How do I split a robot framework keyword in two lines?

Tags: robotframework

I have a very extensive keyword then i'd like to split it in two or more lines.

I tried to use ellipsis (...) but it didn't work.

What I have:

```
This is my very extensive keyword and I would like to split it
```

What I tried:

```
This is my very extensive
... keyword and I would like to split it
```

and (2 spaces)

```
This is my very extensive
...  keyword and I would like to split it
```

Comment: Don't forget that if you were able to split the name during the definition, you world still had to use the full single line on calling, which defies the goal :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do what you want. You can't split a keyword name across multiple lines.